# Hiding app icon from launcher

Tags: java, android

I've tried my best to remove `app icon` from `launcher`, everytime it fails.. Sometimes icon is removed but the app fails to run (I've intergrated the app in `Settings` and `onClick` I called to its `MainActivity`. However normal app runs fine)
can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the launcher icon after running the app this piece of code will do it.  I've hooked mine up to a button on the activity to hide it as the app doesn't need a launcher other than an introductory screen.

```
Button hideLauncherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hideLauncherButton);
hideLauncherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that not all home screen implementations will necessarily detect this state change. On those, the launcher icon will remain, though the activity will not start up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Intent filter for launcher from your AndroidManifest.xml

Remove this

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: tried it for the first time. App removed from launcher but it was unable to start.